# Cloudera HBase Clients for CDH 5.15

Tags: java, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

CDH 5.15 is released as mentioned [here](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-News-Release/ANNOUNCE-Cloudera-Enterprise-5-15-is-Now-Available/m-p/69154#M233). But I don't see any hbase clients specific to CDH 5.15 in the [maven central repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client?repo=cloudera). The latest I can see is of version `5.14.2`.

Are we supposed to use to 5.14.2 clients with CDH 5.15? I could not find anything related to this in CDH documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in cloudera [forum](http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/HBase-Client-for-CDH-15/m-p/69285#M14103)

> mvnrepository.com is an aggregator site, and Cloudera doesn't have
>   control over how often they collect the artifacts.
>
> In the same time, please read this article about using Cloudera's own
>   maven repository: 
>   https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html